# How to increase the count badge when push notification recevied and app is open?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, push-notification, android-actionbaractivity

Hi In my application I have to show unread push notifications count. when the user is already in the app on that case when push is received I have to update the action bar item count in the app.

Here is my code:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment{

    public static final String TAG = "BaseFragment";
    private CustomTextView mTxtTitle;
    public static TextView mReadCount;
    private RelativeLayout mUnreadCount;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View customActionBar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_action_home, null);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBar);
        getActionBarViewIds(customActionBar);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void getActionBarViewIds(View view) {
        mTxtTitle = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        mReadCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.read_count);
        mReadCount.setText("" + Utility.getSharedPrefIntData(getActivity(), Constants.PREF_KEY_NOTIFICATION_COUNT));
        mUnreadCount = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.unread_count);
        mUnreadCount.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Utility.navigateFragment(new NotificationFragment(),
                        NotificationFragment.TAG, null, getActivity());
                Utility.setSharedPrefIntData(getActivity(), Constants.PREF_KEY_NOTIFICATION_COUNT, 0);
            }
        });
    }
```

All the app I am extends my BaseFragment. so I am showing my custom action bar in the total app.

Here I have to update the count when push received.

Answer (score 0):

There is a service which handles push notifications 
as far as I know there was a method called onMessage() you overrice the method to do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Broadcast receiver and listen to it in the BaseFragment. Then you can invalidate the action bar with the new count.